# How to convert unicode original python type

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-unicode

I am posting such data using postman rest client.

```
{ 'name':"xyz",   
    'data':[{'age': 0, 'foo': 1}, {'age': 1, 'foo': 1}]
 }
```

I am geting data as unicode so I could not fetch dictionary value from this type of data.

what I am doing

```
def post(self, request):
     d = request.DATA
     # here prints right data if we "print d"
     # but d is unicode so we could not access dictionary
     for item in d['data]:
         print item
```

How I convert unicode into list as well as list item in dictionary so I can access dictionary items.

Note I am using django rest framework.

Comment: Make sure you're not accidentally posting a literal string through postman.  If the request is valid JSON and has the Content-Type correctly set to `application/json`, then accessing `request.DATA` will return you the decoded python primatives (so a dict of values in this case)

Comment: @TomChristie i have set these values in form-data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> data = u'{ \'name\':"xyz", \'data\':[{\'age\': 0, \'foo\': 1}, {\'age\': 1, \'foo\': 1}]}'
>>> dic = literal_eval(data)
>>> dic['data']
[{'age': 0, 'foo': 1}, {'age': 1, 'foo': 1}]
>>>
```